# Access Gradle Plugin Dependencies in Another Project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am working on a project that requires and prohibits specific dependencies. I currently have a standalone Gradle plugin that has the required deps and attempts to globally exclude some reps. For some reason in the project where I apply the plugin, I am unable to access the dependencies that are implemented in the Gradle plugin. I've been testing the project that implements the plugin via `gradle dependencies` and check and see if the required deps are listed in the tree.

In this example, my plugin is pulling in `group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', transitive: true` and I need to be able to see/know it is being pulled in as a transitive dep into the implementing project.

Gradle plugin **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url mainUrl }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    maven {
        url mainUrl
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
    // ...
    compile(group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', transitive: true)

}
```

The project that implements Gradle plugin **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        maven { url mainUrl
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
    }
    configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'minutes' }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.gradlepluginpath:gradle-plugin:1.0.+'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: "gradle-plugin"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven{
        url mainUrl
    }
}

dependencies {
   //...
}
```

After running `gradle dependencies`, `org.slf4j` does not show up in the dep tree for the implementing project.

Any help is appreciated.

There is also a problem with the global exclude not working. With this block in the gradle plugin **build.gradle**, `log4j` modules are still showing in the dep tree for the implementing project.

```
configurations {
    classpath {
        all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: '*'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not see Gradle plugin dependencies in the application's dependencies whatsoever, they are completely separate by design.

If your Gradle plugin requires/uses `org.slf4j:slf4j-api`, then you define it in your Gradle plugin's Gradle file, which you have done.

If your application also requires `org.slf4j:slf4j-api`, then you need to define the dependency in the application's Gradle file (Kotlin DSL):

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30") {
        isTransitive = true
    }
}
```

> There is also a problem with the global exclude not working. With this block in the gradle plugin build.gradle, log4j modules are still showing in the dep tree for the implementing project.

The build configuration for the plugin and the project are two distinct things. You must enhance your Gradle plugin to exclude `log4j` using the Gradle API:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyCustomGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        Map<String, String> log4j = new HashMap<>();
        log4j.put("group", "org.apache.logging.log4j");
        log4j.put("module", "*");
        project.getConfigurations().all((configuration) -> configuration.exclude(log4j));
    }

}
```

Comment: He can add the dependency through his plugin, however not by depending on it, because it will be on another classpath. He needs to use the `project` instance passed to his plugin to add the dependency.